# How do you add Bash autocompletion to a snap that doesn't have it (example: canonical-livepatch)

Tags: bash, scripts, snap, auto-completion

The `canonical-livepatch` snap does not feature autocompletion for its subcommands. As per the help page, the valid subcommands are:

```
$ canonical-livepatch help
...
COMMANDS:
   config - configure livepatching on the machine
   disable - disable livepatching on the machine
   enable - enable livepatching on the machine
   help - display help
   kernel-upgrade-required - indicate whether a kernel upgrade is required
   refresh - immediately download and apply any available livepatch
   status - show kernel's livepatch status
```

Is there an easy way to add autocompletion for the subcommands in the `canonical-livepatch` snap that works in Bash, without having to modify the snap itself?

A little detail is that the autocompletion should also work for the snap alias `livepatch` I have for the command.

```
$ snap aliases
Command              Alias      Notes
canonical-livepatch  livepatch  manual
lxd.lxc              lxc        -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by creating the following autocompletion script (I've called it `livepatch-completion`):

```
# canonical-livepatch completion script

_livepatch_completion()
{
  # Only autocomplete for first subcommand
  if [ "${#COMP_WORDS[@]}" != "2" ]; then
    return
  fi

  # Define the list of words that will autocomplete and display on double-tab
  COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "config disable enable help kernel-upgrade-required refresh status" "${COMP_WORDS[1]}"))
}

# Initialize the completion function for both the original command and the alias livepatch    
complete -F _livepatch_completion canonical-livepatch livepatch
```

Place the script anywhere you like (for instance `~/.bash_completion`).

Source the autocompletion script by adding this line to your `~/.bashrc` (or any other file that is sourced when you start the terminal):

```
source ~/.bash_completion/livepatch-completion
```

This may not be the most advanced solution, but it works for simply autocompleting the subcommands for any other command, including snaps and aliases.

Comment: I never realized it didn't work with autocompletion, as I always just typed in the status command, etc.  But now I know, and this script worked great.  Thank you!  +1 :)

Comment: `~/.bash_completion` should be a file, it is sourced by `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, so no need to source it.

Comment: if you like to autoload a user completion file instead, much like `/etc/bash_completion.d` you can use the `$HOME/.local/share/bash-completion/completions` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I'm not going to edit the answer further, since I believe you can put the script wherever you want and source it. However, you're more than welcome to edit if you believe another approach is more correct. Thanks! 